# How to configure Oracle and WebSphere AS 7 interaction via SSL?

Tags: ssl, jdbc, oracle10g, websphere-7

I'm trying to configure WAS7 to interact with Oracle via SSL. For connection retrieving I'm using JNDI DataSources. On the Oracle side everything looks fine, OCI applications works.
Server public key I put to "NodeDefaultTrustStore" / "Signer" via "retrive from port" and client certificate for WebSphere to "NodeDefaultKeyStore" / "Personal" and then changed port in database url to 2484.
After all I got error:

```
00000012 DSConfigurati W DSRA8201W: DataSource Configuration: DSRA8040I: Failed to connect to the DataSource. Encountered java.sql.SQLException: Got minus one from a read callDSRA0010E: SQL State = 00000, Error Code = 0.
java.sql.SQLException: Got minus one from a read callDSRA0010E: SQL State = 00000, Error Code = 0
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:412)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:280)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:207)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:139)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:88)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper$2.run(DSConfigurationHelper.java:1664)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:4678)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:4766)
at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper$3.run(DSConfigurationHelper.java:1680)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper.getPooledConnection(DSConfigurationHelper.java:1692)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper.getPooledConnection(DSConfigurationHelper.java:1587)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper.getConnectionFromDSOrPooledDS(DSConfigurationHelper.java:3219)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.DSConfigurationHelper.testConnectionForGUI(DSConfigurationHelper.java:3895)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at com.ibm.ws.management.DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.testConnectionToDataSource2(DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.java:556)
at com.ibm.ws.management.DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.testConnection(DataSourceConfigHelperMBean.java:484)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1085)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:966)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1332)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1225)
at com.ibm.ws.management.commands.AdminServiceCommands$InvokeCmd.execute(AdminServiceCommands.java:251)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.MBeanHelper.invoke(MBeanHelper.java:239)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.ResourceMBeanHelper.testNode(ResourceMBeanHelper.java:816)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.mbean.ResourceMBeanHelper.testConnection(ResourceMBeanHelper.java:262)
at com.ibm.ws.console.resources.database.jdbc.DataSourceDetailAction.execute(DataSourceDetailAction.java:248)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:104)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:353)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.isclite.container.controller.InformationController.processForwardConfig(InformationController.java:217)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(Unknown Source)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.setUpCommandAssistence(WSCUrlFilter.java:933)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.continueStoringTaskState(WSCUrlFilter.java:500)
at com.ibm.ws.console.core.servlet.WSCUrlFilter.doFilter(WSCUrlFilter.java:321)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1048)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInboundPostHandshake(SSLConnectionLink.java:716)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyHandshakeCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:412)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:1058)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLHandshakeIOCallback.complete(SSLHandshakeIOCallback.java:87)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1604)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Got minus one from a read call
at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:285)
at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:286)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1042)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:301)
... 105 more
```

And on Oracle side in listener.log:

```
TNS-12525: TNS:listener has not received client's request in time allowed
TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out
TNS-12606: TNS: Application timeout occurred
```

whether I'm doing? if so, in what could be the problem?

Comment: What is the JDBC connection string that you use? `jdbc:oracle:thin...`

Comment: Yes, jdbc:oracle:thin ..., works fine with jdbc:oracle:oci8, but I want to use thin.